# Getting: "ImportError: Dll load failed: %1 is no valid Win32 application" while trying to compile my first code in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, selenium, importerror

I am currently trying to teach my self python web programming with the turorial "Test-Driven Development with Python". After making it through "learn python the hard way" and having some small programming experience.
After installing all the libaries with pip(selenium and Django) and going through all the steps provided i get this error in my console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S36h.jpg 
while trying to execute this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

The error suggests that my system is not 64-bit while the installed version of python is 64-bit but since my Windows is 64-bit that does make no sense to me. Some solutions to similar problems dealt with it by giving python 3.4 a new Path variable in windows which i do not understand a lot of. I have python 3.4 and 2.7 installed.

I hope i am doing this right since this is my first post and would be greatfull for any help.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a Python 2 conflict. Are you doing all of this in a virtual environment?

Comment: Alright, you need to learn a little bit more about environment variable. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm Then you need to the the right path for your preferred Python intepreter.